# Error sending message to background script: Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist (FireFox Extension Test)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Have a Firefox Extension Pop-up i'm testing that i'm having trouble getting to connected properly to background.js script, content script sends a message and get's this error message in return

`Error sending message to background script: Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

Here is the content script code

```
const pasteBtn = document.getElementById('pasteBtn');

pasteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Send a message to the background script to request the address object
    browser.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "getAddressObject" })
        .then(() => console.log('grabbing addressObj'))
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error sending message to background script:', error);
    });
});
```

and here is the code in the background.js script that it's trying to send a message to, the code logs properly upon popup open, but seems to not be properly listening for message when it's sent

```
console.log('background.js is running') // for debug purposes to check script loaded

// Listen for messages from content scripts
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (message.action === "getAddressObject") {
        console.log('successfully connected to background.js')
        // Send message to the active tab
        browser.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true })
            .then(tabs => {
                browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: "sendAddressObject", addressObj });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error querying tabs:', error);
            });
    }
});
```

tried making message send an async function to await listen, checked manifest.json and it seems to be setup properly and listening for scripts upon extension open